# Posts posted throught Feed Dialog are not increasing monthly active user count (MAU)

Tags: fbdialogs, active-users

I'm posting posts to Facebook using **Feed Dialog**:

```
function gogogo() {
    var bitLyUrl = getQueryVariable('bitLyUrl');
    var hashTag = getQueryVariable('hashTag');
    var message = getQueryVariable('message');

FB.init({ appId: 452707668140903, status: false });

var obj = {
   method: 'feed',
   link: bitLyUrl,
   name: bitLyUrl,
   caption: 'Test'
   description: message + ' ' + bitLyUrl + ' ' + hashTag
};

function callback(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('success');
    }
    else{
      alert('failure');
   } 
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
};
```

I had four different users post using my app (they logged in using their credentials) however when I checked my app settings, monthly active user count is still = 1

Does anyone know if user has to authorize my app in order to count as active user?
Thanks,
Marta